# two connected lists with angular-ui/ui-sortable, disable placeholder in one while enabling it in the other

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui

In my application there is a menu where you can select templates and drag-drop them into the component list. I am using angular-ui ui-sortable for the two connected lists.

I am using a custom placeholder. Unfortunately, it is also visible in the source list.

When the item is dropped into the destination list, source-list stop event fires and some properties are added. This is the place where the back end would actually create the item in the database.

```
ctrl.sortableSrcOptions = {
    placeholder: {
        element: function (currentItem) {
            return $("<div class='component-placeholder'>Place here</div>")[0];
        },
        update: function (container, p) {
            return;
        }
    },
    connectWith: ".componentlist",
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        if (ui.item.sortable.droptarget.hasClass('componentlist')) {
            //add all properties required by items in destination list
        }
    }

};
```

When the destination list receives the item, the source list is restored.

```
ctrl.sortableDestOptions = {
    receive: function (e, ui) {
        //restore original menu
        ctrl.src = angular.copy(ctrl.originalSrc); 
    }
};
```

How could I make the source list not show the placeholder? 
I’ve been trying to make the source list not sortable but then it becomes also not draggable. Would be best if the source list was immutable and a clone would be created when a user starts dragging an item from the menu.

See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Pitchmatt/pen/zvbwPL)

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder visible problem is solved by adding the following to the css:

```
.sourcelist .component-placeholder {
    display:none;
}
```

I left the codepen as it is to show what was the problem in the first place.